# Webdriver Testing automation

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, webdriver

I am using webdriver for automating the tests for a webapp along with Junit.
I keep getting following error:

> "NoHttpResponseException: Target server failed to respond" in a very
>   irregular way.

What could be the cause of this, and how do I avoid it?

Comment: What version of Selenium? What OS? What browser? What version of that browser? Do you have a sample test case?

Comment: looks like i missed everything in that question....
I am using Selenium 2.25, Windows, IE9/Chrome v24

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was because of the Chromedriver, not sure what was going wrong but I stopped getting the exceptions when I moved to IEDriverServer.